# Android Fab icon color is not bright enough

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am using `FloatingActionButton` icon for sharing a resource my icon look like this

[image: not so bright]

It looks like `gray color` is `overlapped`.

My xml for `FloatingActionButton` icon is

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/fab"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
       android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
       android:tint="@android:color/white"
       app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
       app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" />
```

However I want the white color to be bright enough as in this icon

[image: bright icon]

Answer (score 0):

Put like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"/>
```

**Notice it is:**

```
app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white
```

**and not**

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
```

Hope it's helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The fab inherits the colors from the material theme. Make sure that your theme is using the colors you want by changing the primary, primaryDark and acent colors i.e. in **res > values > styles**.

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `android:tint="@android:color/white"` will always give that overlapped look. I didn't find a way to set the color of the icon via an attribute in the `xml`.

What I did is changing the color of the `drawable` (the icon) itself. It is the only way I found to change the color of the icon.

For adjusting icons I mainly use this website: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

You choose your icon and can than choose the color. Then download and import your icon and it will be the right color in your app.